# Waterfall: cascada vs. catarata

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, sinónimos, vocabulario

What is the difference between *cascada* and *catarata* as translations for the English "waterfall"? Are they synonyms, or is there a difference?

Comment: you have the word cataract in English as well. Cataract, a large, powerful waterfall http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cataract_(disambiguation)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In some way are synonyms, but `catarata` is used for big waterfalls. Of course, this is a subjective difference. For a waterfall in a little creek you say `cascada` for sure, but not `catarata`. And, for example, the translation of:

> Niagara Falls → Cataratas del Niágara

¿Son las cataratas del Niágara cascadas? Sí.

Comment: +1. Exactly what RAE says. Catarata = cascada o salto *grande* de agua. So *cascada* is any waterfall, whereas *catarata* are big ones (Niagara, Iguazú, Victoria...)

Answer (score 3):

Catarata refers to a large, rushing MASS of falling water. Cascada refers to a more gentle falling of water, usually broken up into smaller units called "waterfalls."

Answer (score 2):

What passes for a waterfall can be classified into [many different subtypes](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascada#Tipos), not just *casacadas y cataradas*.

One doesn’t usually think of a “rapid” as one, but in a way it is.  Indeed, Wikipedia mentions that:

> Una *rápida* es una característica hidrológica entre una *corrida* (una parte fluida de un arroyo) y una *cascada*.

Don’t confuse *corridas de agua* with *corridas de toros*, though. :)

Answer (score -1):

`Cascada` is the prefered form in Spain, and `catarata`, the one in Latin America.

Comment: I don't agree. I'm from Spain and I use and hear "catarata" for big waterfalls like "Cataratas de Iguazú", "Cataratas del Niágara" or "Cataratas Victoria".

Comment: Good call. But as for small, "anonymous" waterfalls, and in my experience, my point stands.